# How do i get image attachment to a tweet when fetching recent tweets using twitter api v2

Tags: javascript, twitter, fetch-api

so I want to fetch the image attached to a tweet

I'm currently using this endpoint https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent

what can i add to the query to retrieve it

[image: Sample tweet]

Answer (score 0):

https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=media.fields=url

using this query does the job

media.fields=url